# Rhomobile : How to remove bottom toolbar in device

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

Am working on mobile applications using Rhomobile Rhodes. Everything is working fine but I'm having trouble figuring out how to remove the bottom toolbar (with the back, foward, home, refresh) in device.

So How to remove the bootom toolbar in device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the issue solved by

Uncommenting the `@@toolbar = nil` in **application.rb**